# ¿Cómo resolver el error undefined reference to printf de gcc nasm linux?

Tags: c, linux, nasm, asm

como están?
Estoy haciendo un TP para la facultad y me trabé en este punto. El TP es innecesariamente largo para mostrarlo todo acá, así que resumo el error en una situación mas sencilla.

Desde **asm nasm linux** quiero llamar a una función de C, el **printf**. El siguiente es mi código ASM:

```
%include "io.inc"

section .data
    formato DB "Hola, mundo!",10,0
section .text
    global _calcular
    extern _printf

_calcular:

    ; enter
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    
    ; Muestro los resultados que obtuve por pantalla
    push formato                 ; Envio el formato a la pila
    call _printf                  ; Llamo a la funcion printf de C
    add esp, 4
        
    ; leave
    mov ebp, esp
    pop ebp

    ret
```

Ese código en resumen solo intenta utilizar el **printf** para mostrar un **Hola, mundo!** clásico. Les puede parecer raro el _calcular, es que a su vez C llama a este código (si se cambia por main o CMAIN funciona de 10 en SASM). El siguiente es el código en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void _calcular();

int main()
{
  _calcular();
  return 0;
}
```

Ese código como pueden imaginar solo llama a la función _calcular del ASM. Siguen los comando que utilicé para compilar y unir los archivos.

```
nasm -f elf32 print.asm -o print.o;
gcc -m32 -o print print.c print.o
```

Los nombre de los archivos asm y C son ambos **print**, y el comando nos lo pasaron los profesores, así que en teoría debería funcionar. Finalmente, lo mas importante, el mensaje de error:

```
print.o: In function `_calcular':
print.asm:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `_printf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Hace una semana que estoy buscando por internet alguna solución pero hasta ahora solo encontré personas con problemas parecidos pero cuyo error era otro, por ejemplo escribir Printf en lugar de printf, o ejemplo con "camino feliz" donde muestran el uso del printf similar al mío pero sin errores. Así que hasta ahora no pude descubrir como solucionarlo. Dejo algunas cosas que creo podrían servir:

- El código ASM funciona perfectamente en SASM Linux, excepto por que habría que cambiar el _calcular por CMAIN, eso significa que printf no esta mal escrito.
- El error ocurre dentro de la función calcular, así que deduzco que la encontró, el error no sería en el nombre de la función principal.
- Leí que habría que colocar un _ delante del nombre de las funciones, aunque no me queda claro el porque, probé todas las combinaciones colocando _ tanto en la declaración global del printf en ASM como en las llamadas del mismo, no note ninguna diferencia en el mensaje de error.
- Probé variaciones de los comandos de ejecución sin resultados (bueno el mensaje cambio cuando agregue -c pero tengo entendido que no es correcto hacer eso).
- A mucha gente con este error le respondieron que use GCC, yo ya lo estoy usando.

A estas alturas el error podría ser cualquier cosa, el ASM, el C, el comando de compilación, mi entorno de desarrollo.. help me T-T

**EDITO1**

- Agrego como dato que estoy trabajando sobre Windows 10, pero todo esto lo estoy haciendo en una maquina virtual con Linux.

Siguiendo los comentarios, probé sacando los _ tanto de la declaración del **printf** como en su llamada. No hubo cambios en el mensaje de error, anexo una imagen para ilustrar mejor:

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida

Comment: En qué arquitectura estás tratando de compilar/utilizar esto?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, es Linux 32 bits

Comment: Tomando https://montcs.bloomu.edu/~bobmon/Code/Asm.and.C/Asm.Nasm/hello-printf-64.asm.html como referencia (en este tema no tengo experiencia), podrias probar declararlo como `extern printf`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jamichaels/a5e770105615d9e32b18 también lo declara sin el `_`

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si es correcto responder mi propia pregunta, pero pude resolver este problema por mi cuenta y les dejo una posible solución a quienes vean esto dentro de muchos años.

Dentro del código del ASM hay que eliminar la siguiente linea:

`%include "io.inc"`

Es una linea que se coloca automáticamente al crear un nuevo archivo, y que al parecer estaba generando algún tipo de conflicto. Básicamente tuve que hacer fuerza bruta, comentando linea por linea, y casualmente resultó ser esa, no hubo un camino logico a partir de que no encuentre el printf, pero al menos se resolvió el problema.

Gracias a todos.